# Нужен исходник sha256 на Си

Tags: c, ubuntu, sha256

Вопрос может показаться смешным, но я не могу найти рабочие исходники sha256 на Си

[Заголовочный файл для исходника](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/crypt/md5.c.html)

[исходник](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-32/src/crypto/sha/sha256.c.auto.html)

При компиляции вылезает :

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczXVnBI.o: в функции «SHA224»:
shahash.c:(.text+0x1c3): неопределённая ссылка на «OPENSSL_cleanse»
 /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczXVnBI.o: в функции «SHA256»:
shahash.c:(.text+0x27b): неопределённая ссылка на «OPENSSL_cleanse»
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cczXVnBI.o: в функции «SHA256_Final»:
shahash.c:(.text+0x6d8): неопределённая ссылка на «OPENSSL_cleanse»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Я просто хочу получить функцию для хеширования текста алгоритмом sha256, может кто-то сталкивался с похожей проблемой?

Comment: Больше ошибок нет? Самый простой вариант - выбрать все вызовы `OPENSSL_cleanse(...)` из кода (он обнуляет память перед выходом из функций, чтобы в ней нельзя было ничего подсмотреть).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, больше ошибок нет. Убрал, заработало,  хеширую строку "Hello" должно получиться это : `185f8db32271fe25f561a6fc938b2e264306ec304eda518007d1764826381969`, а получается `��v�FN7�O/u�����a-l�f�nj45?`

Comment: Хотя может я неправильно функцию использую `SHA256("Hello",sizeof("Hello"),NULL)`

Comment: Во-первых `sizeof("Hello")` возвращает 6 а не 5, поэтому вы хешируете `Hello,`. Во-вторых вы печатаете результат в двоичном виде... А хотите похоже в шестнадцатеричном.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, конечно в шестнадцатеричном!

Comment: Дык тогда надо печатать соответственно. Например сделать цикл по байтам, и для каждого: `printf("%02x", байт);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, хорошо, спасибо, лучше просто напишу функцию для перевода в шестнадцатеричную систему

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, проверил с помощью strlen и функция возвращает 32 символа вместо 64, это нормально?

Comment: Что вы передали `strlen`, возвращаемое значение `SHA256`? Зря, она ведь ищет первый нулевой байт по указателю, а если его там нет, то вылезает за границы массива. Он же вам не строку возвращает, там нулевых байт может не быть, а даже если они есть - зачем их искать.

Comment: Но да, `SHA256` возвращает массив из 32 байт. Вспомните, что один байт представляется двумя шестнадцатеричными цифрами.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, последний вопрос(думаю он относится к основному вопросу), все отлично работает, но зачем в функции `printf` нужен модификатор `%02x`, не понимаю почему я должен добавлять ноль, в случае если в байте закодировано меньше чем два шестнадцатеричных числа.

Comment: Ну, например у вас есть байт `0x12` и байт `0x3`. Если напечатать их рядом с помощью `%x`, то получится `123`. По такой записи непонятно, какие были исходные байты: `0x12` `0x3`, или `0x1` `0x23`, или вообще `0x1` `0x2` `0x3`. А если использовать `%02x`, то получится `1203`, и вы точно знаете, что `12` - это первый байт, а `03` - второй. Можно еще использовать `%2x`, но тогда вместо нулей будут пробелы, а это немного тупо.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вы мне очень помогли!